# Should you prevent mapping/filtering arrays in render code?

Tags: reactjs, performance

Let's say I have a component that gets passed an array of items. The component first applies some filter or mapping operation and then calls another component to display the result. Eg., something like this:

```js
export default function SOExample({someList}) {
  const listToShow = someList.filter(item => item.showInSOExample);
  return <MyListRenderer list={listToShow}/>;
}

function MyListRenderer({list}) {
  return <ul>{ list.map(item => <li>{item.text}</li>) }</ul>;
}
```

My question is, is this a bad practice? Will this cause unnecessary rerenders of MyListRenderer, because the list instance passed to it will be a different object every time?

In other words, should I instead do this:

```js
export default function SOExample({someList}) {
  const [listToShow, setListToShow] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setListToShow(someList.filter(item => item.showInSOExample));
  }, [someList]);

  return <MyListRenderer list={listToShow}/>;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `someList` also changes on each render?

Comment: @Dupocas why would it be different on each render? That depends on the calling code for `SOExample`. I'm assuming a usecase where it doesn't change on each render.